# Exclusion click ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I'm working on a form using u-router in AngularJS. I created 5 tabs using the u-sref. I did run the next tab when you click "continue", I use state.go. Therefore, I would like to turn off the ability to click and move the form by the so called tabs ui-sref.
How to disable the ability to click on a bookmark ui-sref ?

example:

```
<a ui-sref=".data" class="btn btn-primary">DATA</a>
```

Comment: Please extend your example, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Here is an example similar to us http://embed.plnkr.co/M03tYgtfqNH09U4x5pHC/preview
I want to prevent the passage of the box when I click on the tab called 2 or 3

Comment: Ok got it. In other words, you want to keep the tab highlight system (based on the ui-sref value) and don't want to allow the user to switch by clicking on the tab. Only with your costum "continue" button on something else am i right ?

Comment: So exactly what I mean :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the CSS property `pointer-events: none` to your `<a>` tag. The link won't be clickable any more.

I updated the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Tm1NkvD9LjvPYjcDuJW) you mentioned in your comment with the following changes:

Add class `no-click-link` to CSS:

```
.no-click-link {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Add this class to the `<a>` tags:

```
<div id="status-buttons" class="text-center">
  <a class="no-click-link" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".profile"><span>1</span> Profile</a>
  <a class="no-click-link" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".interests"><span>2</span> Interests</a>
  <a class="no-click-link" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".payment"><span>3</span> Payment</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ;)